# Numerically integrating close to a singularity

Tags: numerical-integration

Suppose you got a function $f(x)$ with a singularity $s$, point $a$ and a small number $\epsilon$.

For what $b$ does this equation hold?
$$\int_{s-a}^{s-\epsilon}f(x) dx + \int_{s+\epsilon}^{s+b}f(x) dx = 0$$
I want to evaluate $b$ to at least 12 digits of precision.

Example:

$f(x)=\psi(x)$, $s=-2$, $a=10^{-5}$, $\epsilon=10^{-12}$

$\psi(x)$ is the Digamma function, which has a singularity when $x=-2$. For what $b$ does this equation hold?
$$\int_{
-2-10^{-5}}^{-2-10^{-12}}\psi(x) dx + \int_{-2+10^{-12}}^{-2+b}\psi(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: $b=0.000010000184\cdots$